# How to do "where exists" in Arel

Tags: sql, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

How do you do a query that includes a "where exists" in Arel? For example on a query like this to show all the suppliers with at least one order:

```
SELECT *
FROM suppliers
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT *
    FROM orders
    WHERE suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id);
```

I see "exists" in the Arel docs http://rubydoc.info/gems/arel/2.0.7/Arel/Nodes/Exists but I'm having trouble using it.

Comment: The relational operator in question is [semi-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin).

Comment: I'm also interested in this.  It seems however that the `exists` node has actually been taken out of the latest version of ARel.  Not sure if there are plans for it in the future.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here you go:

```
suppliers= Supplier.arel_table
orders= Order.arel_table
suppliers_with_orders = Supplier.where(
                          Order.where(orders[:supplier_id]
                                        .eq(suppliers[:id])).exists).to_sql =>
"SELECT `suppliers`.* FROM `suppliers` 
 WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT `orders`.* 
                FROM `orders` 
                WHERE `suppliers`.`id` = `orders`.`supplier_id`))"
```

**Though, an inner join would do this in a more simple - and eventually less performant - way :**

> Supplier.joins :orders

Comment: good one!  Was just about to answer this after your link to that other post about `not exists` thanks again @pedrorolo

Comment: An inner join would be fundamentally different, as it would return multiple copies of the supplier record, one for every order. That's a performance disaster waiting to happen, especially when you combine tests for existence on multiple associations where 10 order, 5 payments, and 20 deliveries combine to give you 1,000 records returned. Exists is more efficient in just about every regard.

Comment: I tried it in Rails 7 and only could make it work using the arel_table in the inner clause  
`Supplier.where(orders.where(orders[:supplier_id]...`

Answer (score -2):

I think that you can neatly use a counter_cache for this one :

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column