# ARel mimic includes with find_by_sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, join, arel

I've got a [fairly complex sql query](https://gist.github.com/1155760) that I'm pretty sure I can't accomplish with ARel (Rails 3.0.10)

Check out the link, but it has a few joins and a `where exists` clause, and that I'm pretty sure is too complex for ARel.

My problem however is that, before this query was so complex, with ARel I could use `includes` to add other models that I needed to avoid n+1 issues.  Now that I'm using find_by_sql, `includes` don't work.  I still want to be able to fetch these records and attach them to my model instances, the way `includes` does, but I'm not quite sure how to achieve this.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I haven't tried joining them in the same query yet.  I'm just not sure how they would be mapped to objects (ie. if ActiveRecord would properly map them to the proper class)

I know that when using `includes` ActiveRecord actually makes a second query, then somehow attaches those rows to the corresponding instances from the original query.  Can someone instruct me on how I might do this?  Or do I need to join in the same query?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Let's pretend that the SQL really can't be reduced to Arel. Not everything can, and we happen to really really want to keep our custom find_by_sql but we also want to use includes.

Then preload_associations is your friend: 
(Updated for Rails 3.1)

```
class Person
  def self.custom_query
    friends_and_family = find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM people")
# Rails 3.0 and lower use this: 
#        preload_associations(friends_and_family, [:car, :kids])
# Rails 3.1 and higher use this: 
    ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(friends_and_family, [:car, :kids]).run
    friends_and_family
  end
end
```

Note that the 3.1 method is much better, b/c you can apply the eager-loading at any time. Thus you can fetch the objects in your controller, and then just before rendering, you can check the format and eager-load more associations. That's what happens for me - html doens't need the eager loading, but the .json does.

That help?

Comment: Thanks!  I had actually discovered the preload_associations as well and it's exactly what I needed!  Forgot to add that here. thx for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that you can do even the most complex queries with Arel. Maybe you are being over-skeptical about it.

Check these:

- [Rails 3: Arel for NOT EXISTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152424/rails-3-arel-for-not-exists)
- [How to do "where exists" in Arel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207139/how-to-do-where-exists-in-arel)

Comment: the answer to that `where exists` post doesn't do a where exists, it does a where in.  The other one however does use exists so I'll check that out.  thx!

Comment: FYI i've actually used that 2nd article to adjust my query, so I'm currently doing a `where in`, So I suppose I don't really need the answer to my original question now.

Comment: Actually, I have been using Arel3 for a few months now, and on this current project I have SQL queries that do things that are several pages long. You can't really do them in ActiveRecord, because ActiveRecord doesn't support things like UNION (that's still in a patch somewhere) and "WITH" clauses. There are workarounds - like construct it with Arel and then call "to_sql" on it, but then you are left with exactly this posters problem - how to use .includes to reduce roundtrip craziness.

Answer (score 1):

@pedrorolo thanks for the heads up on that `not exists` arel query, helped me achieve what I needed.  Here's the final solution (they key is the final `.exists` on the GroupChallenge query:

```
class GroupChallenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :challenge  

  def self.challenges_for_contact(contact_id, group_id=nil)
    group_challenges = GroupChallenge.arel_table
    group_contacts = GroupContact.arel_table
    challenges = Challenge.arel_table
    groups = Group.arel_table

    query = group_challenges.project(1).
              join(group_contacts).on(group_contacts[:group_id].eq(group_challenges[:group_id])).
              where(group_challenges[:challenge_id].eq(challenges[:id])).
              where(group_challenges[:restrict_participants].eq(true)).
              where(group_contacts[:contact_id].eq(contact_id))

    query = query.join(groups).on(groups[:id].eq(group_challenges[:group_id])).where(groups[:id].eq(group_id)) if group_id

    query
  end
end

class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.open_for_participant(contact_id, group_id = nil)
    open.
      joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN challenge_participants as cp ON challenges.id = cp.challenge_id AND cp.contact_id = #{contact_id.to_i}").
        where(['cp.accepted != ? or cp.accepted IS NULL', false]).
      where(GroupChallenge.challenges_for_contact(contact_id, group_id).exists.or(table[:open_to_all].eq(true)))
  end
end
```

Comment: the open_for_participant method can be written in AREL. Use `includes` instead of `joins` and the where(and or) can be written as arel_table[:attribute].eq(arel_table[:arel_attribute]).and().or etc...

Comment: The problem there is that I have to alias `challenge_participants` in this case, because I also include challenge_participants (not shown here) for a different reason.  I know I can also alias in ARel, but can I call `includes` with an aliased ARel table?  Or does it just take symbols?

Comment: I guess you should investigate how to use the operator "include". That is certainly possible to do.

Comment: You may use the operator 'alias' to get an alias to a certain table. ;) (at the end of this page: https://github.com/rails/arel)

Comment: looks like the Rails [includes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) method does not take `ARel::Table` objects.  I tried something like `Model.includes(arel_table)` and I get an `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError:`  I can't see any `include` like method in ARel either.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, there's no 'include' method. Though, you may use the 'join' method with a second parameter stating that you want a left outer join! :-)

Comment: ah ok, I'll look into that thx!  Man... I wish ARel was documented a bit better.  It's hard to know what features exist without docs.

Comment: There are docs: http://www.rdoc.info/github/rails/arel/master, Though, I agree with you, the lack of better documentation makes arel have a somewhat long learning curve. And I don't like its DSL very much. I believe that one day it will be much better...