# Rails 3: Arel for NOT EXISTS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

How do you write a `NOT EXISTS` in Arel? I'm having trouble translating this query into Arel:

```
SELECT * FROM deals 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM reward_deals 
   WHERE reward_deals.deal_id = deal.id 
   AND NOT (
      reward_deals.awarding_type = 'deal' 
      AND reward_deals.deal_id = reward_deals.awarding_id
   )
 )
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the answer, with strange names because I don't know how to give names for a domain that is for me unknown.

```
deals = Deal.arel_table
reward_deals = RewardDeal.arel_table
awarding_condition= reward_deals[:awarding_type].eq('deal')\
                                .and(reward_deals[:deal_id]\
                                       .eq(reward_deals[:awarding_id]))

reward_deals_condition= reward_deals[:deal_id].eq(deals[:id])\
                              .and(awarding_condition.not)
Deal.where(RewardDeal.where(reward_deals_condition).exists.not)
```

Comment: Still, my answer is answering your question, and my suposition is right. Why didn't you mark my answer as correct?!

Comment: Gotta try it out for myself before I can make it as the answer. Looks like that does the trick. Thanks!