# Finding objects only where all of their has_many collections have a value for a specific column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, relational-division

I have an `Album` object that has many `Tracks`. Tracks have a `youtube_uid` column. I'd like to query albums where all of their tracks' `youtube_uids` are present. I know the technique to find albums with tracks where there's at least one track with a `youtube_uid`:

```
Album.left_outer_joins(:tracks).where.not(tracks: { youtube_uid: nil })
```

What would be the ideal query to find an album where every one of its' tracks has a `youtube_uid`?

Comment: Hmm, I think you need to do something like `WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tracks WHERE tracks.youtube_uid IS NULL AND tracks.album_id = album.id)`.

Comment: @max This sounds like we're getting close but run into a syntax error. `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 1: SELECT "albums".* FROM "albums" WHERE (WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELE...`

Comment: `Album.where('NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tracks WHERE tracks.youtube_uid IS NULL AND tracks.album_id = albums.id)')`

Comment: @max That seemed to do the trick. Feel free to post this solution and I can mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to find all albums that do *not* have a track with missing (empty) youtube-uid. So afaik you need a `NOT EXISTS` query.

In sql I would write something like

```
 select * from albums a
 where not exists (select * from tracks where album_id = a.id and youtube_uid is null)
```

So how do we best translate this to activerecord? I see two possibilities:

```
 sql = <<-SQL
   select * from albums a
   where not exists (select * from tracks where album_id = a.id and youtube_uid is null) 
 SQL

 Album.find_by_sql(sql)
```

while this works, and for me being pretty at home in SQL, this feels fine, it is not very "rails-like", so can we improve this?

There is a shorter form:

```
Album.where("not exists (select * from tracks where album_id = albums.id and youtube_uid is null")
```

but this still feels a little too verbose.
Luckily there exists a more rails-like way. In rails 4 you can write:

```
  Album.where(Track.where("album_id = albums.id").where(youtube_uid: nil).exists.not)
```

In rails 5/6 this is no longer possible, and you have to write:

```
  Album.where(Track.where("album_id = albums.id").where(youtube_uid: nil).arel.exists.not)
```

you can easily verify this generates the good sql by adding `to_sql` at the end.

Comment: The query is solid but you go astray when it comes to adapting it to Rails. You don't need to use `find_by_sql` as you can just use `Album.where('NOT EXISTS ...')`. `.exists.not` would work if you called it on the `arel_table` but it won't work on a ActiveRecord Relation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152424/rails-3-arel-for-not-exists

Comment: Thanks. I ran into this error: ` undefined method `exists' for #<Track::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fd461f90de8> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  exists?`. After trying out the suggested method I got: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "albums" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 1: SELECT "tracks".* FROM "tracks" WHERE (album_id = albums.id)...`. Do you think I need a joins clause?

Comment: Thank you @max good suggestions. "going astray" is probably a bit strong, the `find_by_sql` does work. But right, I tested this in rails 4, where it works. In rails 5/6 you have to write `where(...).arel.exists`. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I agree that astray was a bit harsh. The results from `find_by_sql` are less useful though as it returns raw query results instead of a ActiveRecord::Relation object.

Comment: To be explicit: the `find_by_sql` does return `Album`s (so not entirely "raw"), but yes it is no longer chainable, which makes it a lot less useful indeed. So definitely we would/should try to avoid using `find_by_sql`; but in difficult cases I first try to "solve" it  using SQL, and then try to write in `ActiveRecord` (if possible) (so I was showing my thought-process as well which is probably a bit too much information).

Comment: It's worth noting that by using an inverse EXISTS rather than an inner join, this query will also return albums with no tracks at all; it also skips any scopes defined explicitly on the Album::tracks relation.

Answer (score 1):

We shall achieve it with Group by and having as well:

```
Album.left_outer_joins(:tracks).group(:id).having('COUNT(tracks.id) = COUNT(tracks.youtube_uid)')
```