# ActiveRecord: find_by_sql and includes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to use find_by_sql and includes at the same time.

I use find_by_sql because I write select inside from to utilize index.
Somehow, index is ignored if I use left join.

But, find_by_sql does not return ActiveRecord_Relation but returns Array objects, so I cannot write

```
like Model.find_by_sql("select * from (select * from table limit 10)table left join rel_table on ...").includes(:rel_table,...) .
```

I can run two queries and hand-includes after that.
Is there any way to solve it as one SQL?

Comment: Why you want to use find_by_sql method instead you can use rails `joins` then you can use both `joins `and `includes` in same query

Comment: If I use join and include at the same time, index for where and order clause does not work, somehow...

Comment: what is your query for index?

Answer (score 16):

You can't call `includes` on the resulting array, but you can call the Rails preloader manually to do the same thing.

See [ARel mimic includes with find_by_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116087/arel-mimic-includes-with-find-by-sql).

```
array = Model.find_by_sql("select * from ...")

# Rails 3 and 4.0.x
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(array, [:rel_table]).run

# Rails 4.1+
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(array, [:rel_table])
```

Comment: Still works on Rails 6